# Encrypted fs and liblzma.so.5 library missing

Tags: linux, debian, disk-encryption, initramfs, encrypting-file-system

I have created a few VMs with encrypted filesystems + `dropbear-initramfs` (https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/dropbear-initramfs) with a procedure similar to [How to unlock LUKS using Dropbear SSH keys remotely in Linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/security/how-to-unlock-luks-using-dropbear-ssh-keys-remotely-in-linux/).

At first it works, unlocking over SSH works and all is fine.

However after a few reboots and a few days later following error starts pops up several dozen times, unlocking is no longer possible (within that timeframe) and finally it drops into `initrafms`:

[image]

What's happening? How can I fix this?

Environment: Debian 11 x64.